# NAT with masquerade on different interfaces that access different network with Nftables

Tags: networking, debian, nftables

I have a server that is connected to two network :

- 10.0.0.0/24 through an interface wlan0
- 192.168.1.0/24 through an interface eth0

I want to setup a Wireguard VPN to make *both* network accessible from outside. I activated ip forwarding in my config (with sysctl).
Now I need to setup a NAT in order to route my requests from the VPN server through the two local network.
I use nftables to setup the NAT.

My issue is, for a machine with only one interface, I would use the following configuration :

```
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority 0;
    }
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100;
        ip saddr 10.2.0.0/24 oifname eth0 masquerade
    }
}
```

But here, I don't want to route everything through eth0, I want to specifically route everything meant for 10.0.0.0/24 through wlan0 and everything meant for 192.168.1.0/24 through eth0. How can I achieve this with nftables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself in the end, so here is how to do it : You have to use the `ip daddr` parameter to filter by destination address. My final rule set is the following :

```
table ip nat {

        chain PREROUTING {
            type nat hook prerouting priority filter; policy accept;
        }
    
        chain POSTROUTING {
            type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
            ip saddr 10.2.0.0/24 ip daddr 192.168.0.0/16 oifname "eth0" masquerade
            ip saddr 10.2.0.0/24 ip daddr 10.0.0.0/24 oifname "wlan0" masquerade
        }
}
```

This works perfectly.